# Sort by bool on nested child

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following objects:

```
[{
        "some_field": "some_value",
        "nested_objects": [{
            "some_field2": "some_value",
            "nested_objects2": [{
                "some_field": "some_value",
                "bool_field": true
            }, {
                "some_field": "some_value",
                "bool_field": true
            }, {
                "some_field": "some_value",
                "bool_field": false
            }]
        }, {
            "some_field2": "some_value",
            "nested_objects2": [{
                "some_field": "some_value",
                "bool_field": false
            }, {
                "some_field": "some_value",
                "bool_field": false
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "some_field": "some_value",
        "nested_objects": [{
            "some_field2": "some_value",
            "nested_objects2": [{
                "some_field": "some_value",
                "bool_field": false
            }, {
                "some_field": "some_value",
                "bool_field": false
            }, {
                "some_field": "some_value",
                "bool_field": true
            }]
        }]
    }
]
```

All nested objects are mapped as nested objects. I want to sort the top level parent depending on the third level children bool values. Children with more bool values should rank higher than others.

So I basically want to sort by

```
_source.nested_objects.nested_objects2.bool_field
```

Objects with more true values should rank higher than others.

I also want to be able to filter the nested objects like:

```
_source.nested_objects.some_field == "some specific value"
```

Then the score calculation should only be applied to the matching objects and the matching nested objects.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

When I initially read your question, I assumed it wasn't even possible to do beyond that first level of nesting. Luckily, I was able to find [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/problem-looping-through-array-in-each-doc-with-painless/90648/3) forum thread which lead me to a possible solution.

I would like to comment that I believe you would be better served to restructure your data slightly. Normalizing your data and performing a pseudo "join" to calculate the values could be one option.

Another choice (and the one I would learn towards) would be to control a numeric value (some type of count variable you pass with these objects at index-time), or include a script that calculates this value for you at index time. Performing this calculation at index time will allow you to avoid the recurring cost of this relatively expensive script.

Regardless of where you go with it, I think the below should fit your current goal:

```
POST /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }, 
  "sort": [
    {
     "_script":{
       "type":"number",
           "script": {
      "lang": "painless", 
      "source": "int bool_sum = 0;for(int i = 0; i < params._source.nested_objects.length;i++){for(def j = 0; j < params._source.nested_objects[i].nested_objects2.length; j++){if(params._source.nested_objects[i].nested_objects2[j].bool_field == true)bool_sum++;}}return bool_sum;"
    }
     }
    }
  ]
}
```

The nasty little script formatted for cleaner reading:

```
int bool_sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < params._source.nested_objects.length;i++)
        for(def j = 0; j < params._source.nested_objects[i].nested_objects2.length; j++){
            if(params._source.nested_objects[i].nested_objects2[j].bool_field == true)
                    bool_sum++;
return bool_sum;
```

I updated this based on your comments to allow you to do a comparison using an input parameter:

```
POST /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "nested_objects.nested_objects2.bool_field": true
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "script": {
          "params": {
            "value_to_match": false
          },
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": "int bool_sum = 0;for(int i = 0; i < params._source.nested_objects.length;i++){for(def j = 0; j < params._source.nested_objects[i].nested_objects2.length; j++){if(params._source.nested_objects[i].nested_objects2[j].bool_field == params.value_to_match )bool_sum++;}}return bool_sum;"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And the updated script:

```
int bool_sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < params._source.nested_objects.length;i++)
        for(def j = 0; j < params._source.nested_objects[i].nested_objects2.length; j++){
            if(params._source.nested_objects[i].nested_objects2[j].bool_field == params.value_to_match)
                    bool_sum++;
return bool_sum;
```

Comment: Calculate the value at index time is not possible since I want to be able to create a query that matches a subset of the nested objects and then I don't want the aggregated value of all nested objects.

Comment: The script probably won't work because of the same reasons?

Comment: You're correct, if you're aiming to get counts for a subset of the nested items then the calculated value on the root wouldn't be valid. However, if you have a hit on the top level object, I don't believe it's possible to only return a subset of the child objects while still returning the parent.

If this is the requirement, I would think normalizing the data would be your best bet.

Comment: @MagnusO. I edited the answer to allow you to compare an input value rather than take the static t/f as the counter

Answer (score 0):

I might have found something that works. I can created nested queries and add the scores of the nested objects to the parent like:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "sort": [{
        "_score": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "nested": {
                    "query": {
                        "nested": {
                            "query": {
                                "term": {
                                    "nested_objects.nested_objects2.bool_field": {
                                        "value": true
                                    }
                                },
                                "score_mode": "sum"
                            },
                            "path": "nested_objects.nested_objects2",
                            "score_mode": "sum",
                        }
                    },
                    "path": "nested_objects",
                    "score_mode": "sum",
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

If I understand it correctly then the parent would get a better score based on the matching nested objects and the more matching nested objects the parent has the higher the score gets.

Is this correct?